# verifying contents of a resolved promise via function call with chai-as-promised

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon, chai-as-promised

I'm using chai-as-promised in conjunction with sinonjs and I'm unable to work out how to verify a changed password.

I have something like the following code:

```
it('changes password if old password is valid', function(){

    var u = new User({id: '1234567890', email:'user@email.com'});
    var encrypted_password = bcrypt.hashSync('newtestPassword', bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    sinon.stub(db, 'executeQuery', function() {
        return q.fcall( function() {
            return [ {u: { _data: { data: {flake_id: '1234567890', email:'user@email.com', encrypted_password: encrypted_password}}}}];
        })

    })

    return  u.ChangePassword('testPassword', 'newTestPassword').should
                  .eventually.be.an.instanceof(User)
                  .and.have.property('encrypted_password')
                  .that.satisfy(bcrypt.compareSync('newTestPassword', this));
});
```

Where `u.ChagePassword()` returns a promise.

My problem is the last line of the assertion - I want to be able to extract the encrypted password from the stubbed database response and user bcrypt.compareSync() to check that it is the correct value, but I'm unclear on how to reference the encrypted_password value from the response.

According the the docs, the `property()` call makes that property the subject of the assertion which is why I tried to use `this` but I end up with bcrypt throwing an 'Incorrect arguments' error which I presume is due to the `this` reference.

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to do this properly?

note: I do intend to replace the stub with a mock that checks the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having more of a JavaScript problem than a testing problem. What you have is essentially the same as:

```
var result = bcrypt.compareSync('newTestPassword', this);

return u.ChangePassword('testPassword', 'newTestPassword').should
              .eventually.be.an.instanceof(User)
              .and.have.property('encrypted_password')
              .that.satisfy(result);
```

which should make the issue clearer. `this` in your case is `mocha`s test function context object, not your property.

`.satisfy` expects a function, so I'd do either:

```
.that.satisfy(function(hash){
    return bcrypt.compareSync('newTestPassword', hash);
});
```

or use `.bind`, though it's probably more confusing:

```
.that.satisfy(bcrypt.compareSync.bind(bcrypt, 'newTestPassword'));
```

Comment: thanks! I hadn't noticed that `satisfy` expected a function. Also wasn't really clear about what it would pass in to the function. I used that first suggested solution which worked fine. I agree that the second is a bit obscure in the reading.